# Bijection of infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For any set $A$ such that $A$ has a bijection with $A\times A$ , prove that there's a bijection between $P(A)$ and $P(A) \times P(A)$, where $P(A)$ is the power set of $A$.

Comment: There will be a bijection between $P(A)$ and $P(A \times A) $ Does it help ?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Recall that if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint then $\mathcal P(A)\times\mathcal P(B)$ has a bijection with $\mathcal P(A\cup B)$. Show that the condition of $A$ implies that $A$ and $A\times\{0,1\}$ have a bijection.

Comment: i was not aware of the fact u stated cud u please explain why it happens ,i.e f A and B are disjoint then P(A)×P(B) has a bijection with P(A∪B).

Comment: There's a really obvious bijection between the two sets, you should be able to come up with on your own.

Comment: for finite sets its clear, but for infinite sets it doesn't seem to be clear to me

Comment: Because you insist to think about it in terms of "number of elements" and not the elements themselves.

Comment: ok i got it <X,Y> ->X∪Y, im sry but than AxA has |A|^2 elements and  |A|x{0,1} has 2|A| elements, i mean how does the theorem help as neways A and A are not disjoint.

Comment: First of all note that $A$ is infinite. Infinite cardinalities behave differently than finite cardinalities. Use the Cantor-Bernstein theorem to conclude the second part of the hint; show there is an injection from $A$ into $A\times\{0,1\}$ and from $A\times\{0,1\}$ into $A\times A$, and using the assumption conclude that $|A|=2|A|$. Now we can think about $A\times\{0,1\}$ instead of $A$. Write it as $A\times\{0\}\cup A\times\{1\}$, and finish the proof.

Comment: U rock!! Thanks alot!